# strongloop mongodb connector hangs while loading json data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connector, strongloop, loopbackjs

I had created a model a basic strong loop model. Then I started the strongloop project and using the explorer I tried to load the below data via explorer and the page hangs. I dont see any errors or exceptions thrown on the server. But the web page becomes unresponsive.

Also I dont think this is an issue with any data values below because this data was already present in another mongo collection.

{
  "cvsName" : "cvs_OrderVolume",
  "database" : "pst",
  "description" : "Orders Previous Year to Date by Month",
  "detailedDescription" : "",
  "displayRank" : "89",
  "graphTitle" : "Previous Year to Date",
  "graphType" : "line",
  "linearResult" : ["2012-01", "2012-02", "2012-03", "2012-04", "2012-05", "2012-06", "2012-07", "2012-08", "2012-09", "2012-10", "2012-11", "2012-12", "2013-01", "2013-02", "2013-03", "2013-04", "2013-05", "2013-06", "2013-07", "2013-08", "2013-09", "2013-10", "2013-11", "2013-12", "2014-01", "2014-02"],
  "link" : "",
  "name" : "OrderVolumePreviousYear2DateByMonth",
  "pageId" : "newCustomerByMonth",
  "query" : "this is a complex select query which I cant print here.",
  "result" : [22644, 21752, 20586, 18608, 20239, 20326, 20435, 22298, 20341, 23225, 21089, 18053, 23104, 23416, 24491, 23826, 23436, 23139, 25734, 29617, 24300, 24316, 19946, 18964, 22291, 17900]
}

Update:
I think this has something to do with the type "array" and strong loop.
models.js
"linearResult": {
        "type": "array"
      },
"result": {
        "type": "array"
      }

I have arrays in my database which generally falls in these formats
1. ["2012-01", "2012-02"... about 50 values]
2. [1,2,2,1,.... around 100 values]
3. [[1,21,32,12], [2,12,4,3]... around 50 values] (I dont think the number of values makes any sense here. But thought its worth mentioning)

I see that the data is inserted in mongoDB. But of the above 3 formats result and linear result has [null, null, null ... around 100 times] for the 2nd and 3rd format of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please open an issue at https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/issues? A test case to demonstrate your issue will be helpful for us to troubleshoot the issue.

Thanks,
Raymond

Comment: I just did. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Per Raymond changed the defenition of the array in models.json as type:["Any"]. you could also use type:["Number"] or type:["String"] to make it work. ["Any"] would work if your array is hybrid with string, number or objects.